# Ubuntu for old Amilo Pro

Tags: drivers, laptop, versions

I recently installed Ubuntu on my pc and I was amazed how fast it is. My parents got old laptop which they use only for surfing the Web and watching movies sometimes (they just plug tv into it and watch from HDD). It's Fujitsu-Siemens Amilo Pro v2055. I wanted to install Ubuntu on this "rig", I have a feeling it will perform much better than WinXp. It's technical parameters are: 1.6 Ghz Intel Celeron M420, 1 GB Ram, VIA/S3G Unichrome 64 MB GPU, 80 GB HDD. So, my question is: which version would run well on this machine? And are the drivers available?

Shando

Comment: That rig is very old, and Unichrome GPU support is very bad indeed. My advice is - stay with XP.